# Number of Git revisions as a parameter to MSBuild in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a Git project in TFS. By executing a Powershell script locally, I can use "git rev-list HEAD --count" to get the number of revisions and then use that as a parameter to MSBuild. I need to achieve the same while building a project on TFS.

In the Build Definition, I can specify MSBuild Parameters, but it seems like I cannot use "$(git rev-list HEAD --count)" as a variable.

Is there any way I can get the current number of revisions and use that for the ApplicationRevision property?

I tried changing the workflow, but it got me nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify a powershell script using the Pre-Build Script Path argument to TFS Build.  That script can run your git command then stuff the result into an Environment variable.  Then from MSBuild you could read that environment variable.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use Environment variables with powershell.. :(